# Teamcity Android Ant CI debug and release apk

Tags: android, ant, continuous-integration, teamcity

I ran into a problem that I'm not too sure on how I should go solving.
Currently I have an android project building with an ANT script in team city. The ant script is building the apk with the debug key.This part is fine and is working as expected.

However, now when we need to submit the application to the store, I have to manually create the signed release apk. I was thinking that I could make another configuration that always builds in signed release but that seemed like a horrible way to do it.
Is there a way I can set up my configuration to run in debug all the time except when I pass a specific parameter through teamcity to run in release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone runs into this problem. What I ended up doing was making a build step to do all the preparations for release mode IE passing in the right parameters to the ant script, as well as putting the keystore password,however this build step checks for a Configuration parameter that I made that is either debug or release.
When I set the parameter to always be debug, and when I need to do release mode, I make a custom build with the parameter as release and the Release Build step will take effect.